# Firefox extensions equivalent with chrome's

Tags: firefox-addon

I have one question:

There is the **"matches"** pattern in a manifest.json file which says under which domain the extension should function.

Is there the same for the firefox extension? Or must be determined in a js file?

If the second option is the correct one, could someone tell me how? Up to now, I get the url of the tab about 10 times (using alerts).

If you know any website which provide examples for 100% amateurs for ff extensions, I would appreciate it, its 2 days I crawl the internet without stopping but I cant find a complete solution!

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox addons don't necessarily run on a per-website basis -- they can exist independently of this (like a weather widget, for example). If you want to modify a page, based on its URL, you can use the [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) module in the Addon SDK. [Here's a tutorial to do just that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL).

Comment: That looks even more complicated. On the other hand, having a listener (I guess I put that right) in order to retrieve the webpage's domain, makes the addon to make several checks (I realized that using alerts). This cant help me because I want to inject a div into the webpage right after the domain is found to be the correct one. With these several checks, that div will be injected same times as the checks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- the page-mod implementation does not inject content fast enough?

Comment: The code in your suggestion, where it should be added? In the xul or js file?

Comment: When making a Jetpack addon with the addon-sdk, you should not have to access any XUL unless doing something more complicated. At the top of the tutorial page, there are links for getting set up. The code for a page-mod should just live in your main js file (`./lib/main.js`) for a simple edit

Comment: It says I need to install the SDK, I dont know anything about Python :S